# Renaming multiple files with the same extension using PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, rename

I would like to rename just the csv files in my **H:/DMU** folder. I tried the following code:

```
 Dir -filter *.csv | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("fn*.csv" -f $nr++)}
```

I encountered the following error for every file I tried to convert. [PowerShell Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuMcM.png)

I know how to rename all the files in this folder to include the prefix "*fn"*

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude "fn*" |rename-item -NewName {"fn" + $_.Name
```

, but I just don't know how to rename those of a particular extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've copied some code that you don't really understand. Where is `$nr` & why is it being incremented? YOu don't mention wanting to number the files, just add a prefix.

To rename by adding a simple prefix:

```
gci -filter *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName { 'fn' +$_.Name }
```

If you want to number:

```
[ref]$i = 1
gci -filter *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName { 'fn' + $i.Value++ + $_.Name }
```

If you want 3-place numbering with preceding zeros:

```
[ref]$i = 1
gci -filter *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName { 'fn{0:d3}{1}' -f $i.Value++, $_.Name }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to just add a prefix. I was using code that I modified from another website that referred to renaming a file with a specific extension, but it did not discuss how to prefix multiple files with a specific extension. I did not understand the role of the $nr.

So gci is a shorter way of saying get-child-item--that's interesting. Additionally, I didn't know that double quotes and single quotes were interchangeable in PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, `gci` is an _alias_ for `Get-ChildItem`. There are a number pre-defined & you can also define your own. Check the output of `Get-Alias`.